# How to display more columns on webpage than the width of my screen

Tags: html, sql, display

I have a 2 tiered structure in my database, with a 1-to-6 master-to-slaves table structure. The info in all 7 tables amounts to 40-50 columns, mainly text, which cannot be displayed on a single screen, except if you use a horizontal scroll bar, which, for some reason, I don't want to do.

I thought of the following strategy to display all columns:

(1) I use a html form with some fixed filters and some dynamic ones, which is recursive (it calls itself). There is a common group of columns located leftmost in the table, which originates in the master table and appears in every screen, and a dynamic group of columns, displayed further right, as the screen permits.

(2) The other columns, displayed to the right of the leftmost columns, originate from the slave tables, and can be changed.

(3) The input being recursive, you can select a new group of columns (i.e. query another slave table) using the previous settings of the form. This is done by modifying a drop-down list (located at the top of my form), where the user selects which group of columns he wants to see, i.e. which slave table to query and display.

I could also display every such distinct group of columns in a new browser tab (I use Mozilla). This would be more cumbersome, because the user would have to switch back and forth from one tab to the other, and if he scrolls down in one tab, he would hqave to sync all other tabs manually. The first column  in each tab would be an id column, to enable him to synchronize the tabs.

My strategy enables me to keep the queries to reasonable sizes of lengths & complexity, also keeping the load of the DB server in check.

The lines/columns are displayed using HTML tables.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This question will probably heavily depend on what your Software Product Owner / Customer will accept. Below is an idea of using a gridview control with expandable rows. Maybe this is an option that would be acceptable, and you would put the more important values in the non-expanded portion of the grid, see below:

[image]

Alternatively, you could also allow the users to select which columns they wish to see.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a new idea. However, since I have a unique id for my master rows, I decided to accept the solution with the horizontal scroll bar and have the first and last column display this id.

Comment: The columns won't be longer than 2 screen widths, so pushing the scroll bar to its extreme left / extreme right will enable the user to see one of the halfs, without missing anything. I keep thinking what I would've done in Visual Studio or Excel, and something else than hiding colums doesn't come to mind.

Comment: ... and obviously, with HTML tables one cannot hide columns or resize them interactively - or can they ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a jquery ui multi select drop down that you could add to your page allowing users to select the columns that are important to them.